# Necesito este ejercicio en neatbeans por favor ayuda! Estoy empezando

Tags: java

Diseñe un algoritmo al que le ingresen numeros, sumara los positivos, pero al ingresarle 3 veces un numero negativo debe salir del programa y mostrar la sumatoria de los positivos.

Comment: Hola Andres, Bienvenido al sitio, el voto en contra no es mio, pero entiendo por te lo han dado, es necesario que nos muestres como has implementado este algoritmo para poder ayudarte a resolver cualquier problema que tienes con el. Puedes editar la pregunta y agregar todo el código que sea necesario para que podamos entender y reproducir el problema en nuestras computadoras. A propósito, el editor tiene suficientes elementos para darle buen formato al código y demás. Si no puedes hacerlo, seguramente tu pregunta acabara cerrada y no podra recibir mas respuestas. Saludos y bienvenido de nuevo.

Comment: @rnd tristemente, he aquí otro ejemplo de lo que te comenté en la respuesta del meta, tanto por esta pregunta y por su respuesta

Comment: Está bien pedir ayuda con problemas técnicos específicos pero no pedir que te hagan la tarea.

Answer (score 5):

Primero debes de importar las librerías:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

Después creas la instancia

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Después creas las variables necesarias:

```
int total = 0;
int num;
int contador_negativos = 0;
```

Ahora procedemos a pedir la información:

```
while(contador_negativos < 3){
    System.out.println("Ingrese un número: ");
    num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if(num < 0){
        contador_negativos++;
    }else{
        total += num;
    }
}
System.out.println("El resultado es: " + total );
```